# jsreport - Access is denied message in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, jsreport

I'm having an `Access Denied` message while executing this code:

```
var report = await _service.RenderAsync(new RenderRequest
{
     Template = new Template
     {
         Recipe = Recipe.PhantomPdf,
         Engine = Engine.None,
         Content = html,
         Phantom = new Phantom()
         {
             Header = header,
             Footer = footer,
             HeaderHeight = GetElementHeightOrDefault(header),
             FooterHeight = GetElementHeightOrDefault(footer)
         }
      }
 });
```

Actually it fails while executing the `_service.RenderAsync` method, a service that implements from `IRenderService`.

This is the error message:

```
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at jsreport.Local.Internal.BinaryProcess.<InnerExecute>d__18.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at jsreport.Local.Internal.BinaryProcess.<ExecuteExe>d__17.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at jsreport.Local.Internal.LocalUtilityReportingService.<RenderAsync>d__10.MoveNext()
   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

I found this thread from `jsreport` in which there's people with the same problem as me: [formu.jsreport.net/topic/428](https://forum.jsreport.net/topic/428/asp-net-an-error-has-occurred-when-trying-to-initialize-jsreport/17)

So I followed this steps:

1. As I have a Web application and an IIS Api service in IIS, I added both IUSR and IIS_IUSRS to the applicaitons and gave them the highest permissions
2. Ensured that my solution was executed under admin privileges
3. Disabled all antivirus and Windows Security

But *none of these* worked. I'm still fancing the same problem here.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Can you try to change the impersonation in your AppPool to admin user: IIS > Application Pools > Advanced Settings > Identity (and change it to the Admin account)

Comment: I had to change it to LocalSystem identity. Not sure why, but it worked. I would like it to work under ApplicationPoolIdentity... but can you share your question as an answer? it drove me to the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably it's something related to the impersonation, so if the code not executed under a specific impersonation context and all of the code runs through the IIS Impersonation so we may need to make some trails related to the AppPool:

1. Try to change the impersonation in your AppPool to admin user:

> IIS > Application Pools > Advanced Settings > Identity (and change it
>   to the Admin account).

2. Give the directory which contains the rendering stuff an `everyone`
   permission.

Also, as per your comment, The local system has the highest privilege while network service or ApplicationPoolIdentity has the least-privilege to execute the application so that's why local system can solve most of the impersonation issues .